# two sections and different three cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

1.I have one more section1

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    }else{
        return 3 //imageName.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var thirdCell = ThirdTableViewCell()
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    var row2Cell = Row2TableViewCell()

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }else if indexPath.row == 1{
        thirdCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell
        thirdCell.image1.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus")//imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return thirdCell
    }else{
        row2Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Row2Cell", for: indexPath) as! Row2TableViewCell
        return row2Cell
    }
}
```

[image: I have one more section1]

2.How did I get ThirdViewController.image

[image: How did I get ThirdViewController]

Comment: What's your question? `var thirdCell = ThirdTableViewCell()`. That's creating unnecessary a new cell each time.

Comment: `self.image = UIImage()` instead of ThirdViewController.image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you want to access **ThirdViewController.image**  in your **ThirdTableViewCell Class**

this is how you can access instance of viewController (e.g Labels, Images and TextFeilds etc) in other View Controller or in custom class.

```
import UIKit

internal weak var AccessThirdViewController: ThirdViewController?

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewToChange: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        AccessThirdViewController = self
    }
```

**it will make it accessible in all other viewControllers or classes**

```
import UIKit

class ThirdTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func onButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        AccessThirdViewController?.imageViewToChange.image = UIImage(named: "rocket")!
    }


}
```

Now you can simply access ThirdViewController directly using **AccessThirdViewContoller**

> Or you can achieve this by using NotificationCenter as creating
>   NotificationCenter addObserver

***Receive(Get) Notification and Function-Method handler for received Notification:***

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

     @IBOutlet weak var imageViewToChange: UIImageView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setImage), name: Notification.Name("UpdateImage"), object: nil)
     }

     @objc func setImage(){
          self.imageViewToChange.image = UIImage(named: "rocket")
      }
```

**Then Send(Post) Notification from ThirdTableViewCell Class on @IBAction of UIButton**

```
import UIKit

class ThirdTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        @IBAction func onButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("UpdateImage"), object: nil)
       }


 }
```

Comment: If it does solved your problem please give it Upvote and mark as answered close the problem.